# Parameterize Spock setup

Tags: unit-testing, testing, spock

Is it possible to parameterize a Spock `setup`?

By that I mean, imagine I have an object whose state I want to test.  The object can have multiple states, but to simplify things, let's say there's one I'm particularly interested in, `S1`.

There are multiple ways to get the object to `S1`.  I'm testing state, so all the tests for `S1` will be the same regardless of how the object reached `S1`.  The one thing that would differ between test cases would be the `setup` strategy.

One way to deal with this is to have a base test case (or "spec" to use Spock parlance) and subclasses that only supply different `setup` strategies.

But, given the nice data-driven features of tests that Spock offers, I got to wondering if there might be some way to parameterize the setup in such a way that I wouldn't need concrete subclass specs.

In effect, I would be saying, here's a spec, now run it with these different ways of executing setup.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? Isn't data-driven testing what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always nice to have at least a bit of code as example, but here you go.
Trying to put your words into a data-driven Spec:

```
class MyObjectSpec extends Specification {

    @Unroll
    def "Using setup strategy '#desc', instance of MyObject will reach state S1" {

        setup:
        def myObject = new MyObject()
        setupStrategy.call(myObject)

        expect:
        hasStateS1(myObject)

        where:
        setupStrategy           | desc
        { setupThisWay(it)    } | 'this way'
        { setupThatWay(it)    } | 'that way'
        { setupAnotherWay(it) } | 'another way'
    }

    void setupThisWay(MyObject myObject) {
        // mutate myObject
    }

    // setupThatWay, setupAnotherWay

    void hasStateS1(MyObject myObject) {
        assert myObject.hasStateS1()
    }
}
```

We are using Groovy closures, defined inline in the data table to call helper methods that mutate your newly created object.

In this case, there is no `when` block, because you kind of implied that you wanteded the interesting part to happen in `setup` (which is the same as `given`), and `expect` is a `then`, that doesn't need a `when`.

The helper methods are of type `void`, and do their own assertions, as suggested [in the Spock documentation](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/spock_primer.html#_helper_methods) (in fact making the `then`/`expect` no-op, however the Spock compiler enforces it anways).

Data-driven docs are [here](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/data_driven_testing.html).